# Computer Vision - template matching algorithms

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Can someone recommend me some good bibliographic material regarding template matching algorithms and techniques? (book, articles, matlab functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.hoepli.it/libro/fundamentals-of-digital-image-processing/9780470844731.asp

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516130

i've bought these 2 books for my thesis, template matching is well explained (especially in the first one).

i also suggest http://www.araa.asn.au/acra/acra2004/papers/cole.pdf which is a well written article (from wikipedia) and maybe check out the OpenSURF (c++ library for features extraction) paper http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html

Answer (score 1):

Functions for template matching in software systems:

Matlab offers normxcorr2 to perform normalized cross correlation.

Mathematica offers the function ImageCorrelate. Its third argument covers all the classical distance functions used in template matching:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageCorrelate.html